# Is dynamic action name building a bad practice?

Tags: actions

I'm looping through some posts to delete them:

```
/**
 * Holds deletion errors.
 */
$errors = [];

foreach( $imported_posts as $imported_post ) {
    $post_id = $imported_post->ID;

    /**
     * Actually delete the post.
     */
    $deletion = wp_delete_post( $post_id );

    if( !$deletion || is_null( $deletion ) ) {
        $errors[] = new \WP_Error(
            'failed-deleting-post',
            sprintf(
                esc_html__( 'Post with ID: %s could not be deleted.' ),
                $post_id
            )
        );
    }

    unset( $post_id );
}
```

And I was thinking that maybe I can allow a hook on `delete error` for people to use and see what went wrong. I would then do this:

```
do_action( 'setup_theme\after_imported_post_' . $post_id . '_delete_failed' );
```

But, come to think of it, is there any way to hook into this without a regex and complicated loops?

The alternative, much cleaner would be:

```
do_action( 'setup_theme\after_imported_post_delete_failed', $post_id );
```

I saw a few plugins that do this dynamic thing and I could never figure out how to hook into them. For example, Elementor:

```
do_action( "elementor/css-file/{$name}/parse", $this );
```

How does this all work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually yes, sometimes no, **but in your example, definitely bad practice**

You see, instead of putting the name or the post ID in the action name, you should have passed it as a parameter instead. Otherwise there is no way to grab all elementor css file parsing, or no way to work after any arbitrary after imported post. You need to know in advance every possible post ID or name that could turn up, making the action very limited in use.

Examples where it might make sense, are where it's shorthand for an entire class of objects. This is a rarer situation, but an example would be `publish_posts` versus `publish_book` where `book` is a custom post type.

Note that in those situations, these are additional actions/hooks that are done in addition to not instead of generic hooks.